# I can't figure out: User Control with ComboBox bubbling up SelectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I can't seem to get this working. It is easy with sliders and any controls which pass simple types, but I cannot seem to figure out how to bubble up a ComboBox SelectionChanged with its ComboBoxItem.

This always fails with:

InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException
                                     Message=The type initializer for 'Module.Dashboard.KpiComboBox' threw an exception.
                                     TypeName=Module.Dashboard.KpiComboBox
                                     InnerException: System.ArgumentException
                                          Message=Default value for the 'Value' property cannot be bound to a specific thread.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using PA.DPW.PACSES.CAL.Infrastructure;

namespace Module.Dashboard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for KpiComboBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class KpiComboBox : UserControl
    {
        public KpiComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called to bind the proper KPIs to the cboKpi, according to which View name you pass
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="viewName">Use Constants viewnames</param>
        /// <example>
        /// kpiComboBox.BindComboBox(Constants.CountyMapViewName);
        /// </example>
        public void BindComboBox(string viewName)
        {
            List<KPICodeDescription> lstKpi = null;

            switch (viewName)
            {
                case Constants.CountyMapViewName:
                    lstKpi = UtilityHelper.GetKpiList(Constants.CountyMapViewName);
                    break;
                case Constants.CountyRankingsViewName:
                    lstKpi = UtilityHelper.GetKpiList(Constants.CountyRankingsViewName);
                    break;
                case Constants.StateMapViewName:
                    lstKpi = UtilityHelper.GetKpiList(Constants.StateMapViewName);
                    break;
                case Constants.StateRankingsViewName:
                    lstKpi = UtilityHelper.GetKpiList(Constants.StateRankingsViewName);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (lstKpi != null)
            {
                cboKpi2.ItemsSource = lstKpi;
                cboKpi2.DisplayMemberPath = "KPIDescription";
                cboKpi2.SelectedValuePath = "KPICode";
            }
        }

        // Dependency Object for Bubbling

        private ComboBoxItem value;

        public ComboBoxItem Value
        {
            get { return (ComboBoxItem)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnSelectionChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            KpiComboBox cboControl = (KpiComboBox)sender;

            cboControl.value = (ComboBoxItem)args.NewValue;
            cboControl.OnSelectionChanged((ComboBoxItem)args.OldValue, (ComboBoxItem)args.NewValue);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(KpiComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(new Object(), OnSelectionChanged));
           //DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(ComboBoxItem), typeof(KpiComboBox));

        // Event Bubbling

        public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectionChangedEvent =
           EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SelectionChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(KpiComboBox));


        // Provide CLR accessors for the event
        public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<ComboBoxItem> SelectionChanged
        {
            add { AddHandler(SelectionChangedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(SelectionChangedEvent, value); }
        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged(ComboBoxItem oldValue, ComboBoxItem newValue)
        {
            RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<ComboBoxItem> args = new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<ComboBoxItem>(oldValue, newValue);
            args.RoutedEvent =  KpiComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent;
            RaiseEvent(args);
        }

        // This method raises the SelectionChanged event
        void RaiseSelectionChangedEvent()
        {
            RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(KpiComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent);
            RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
        }

        private void cboKpi2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello from UC");
            RaiseSelectionChangedEvent();
            //cboKpi2.SelectedItem =;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer would be did you try replacing

```
DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(KpiComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(new Object(), OnSelectionChanged));
```

with

```
DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(ComboBoxItem), typeof(KpiComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectionChanged));
```

?

However, I fail to see why that's necessary - isn't ComboBox.SelectionChanged **already** a routed event? Meaning you can listen for it at any level, regardless of the type of actual control, if somewhere down the hierarchy you have ComboBox? Also, there are even easier ways to do it, if you're using MVVM. Go on, ask me more, I could go on for hours :)

Comment: Still does not work. But, much appreciated. Do you know a simpler way to do this then? That would be ideal.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you attach the handler, but in case you link them from XAML you can try attaching anywhere higher in the hierarchy (above the combobox) the Selector.SelectionChanged routed event; the event handler will be executed every time the selection changes in any element derived from Selector below the FrameworkElement you define the handler on.

Comment: However, the absolute best way is to not need the selection changed event related to the UI at all; instead, using MVVM, have a ViewModel that defines an ICollectionView that represents the collection of ITEMS that will be displayed in the ComboBox (and bind the combobox to this collection), and the ICollectionView will be automatically notified when the selection changes. Completely separated from the View (XAML). And unit-testable. Quite awesome. I highly recommend it.

Comment: Actually it depends on why you need a derived ComboBox at all. If (judging from your code) you only need it to provide a different source for the items... please please don't take this the wrong way, but you're doing it wrong. WPF can be quite painful if used that way, trust me - while the alternative (MVVM) is smooth as silk. The infrastructure of the combobox, for example, is so complicated (and I can explain it at length, but Dr. WPF does a much better job here: http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/) that using it against how it's intended can prove challenging.